# diff between 2 directories excluding few file extensions

Tags: unix

diff between 2 directories and I want to exclude few file extension.

I want to exclude few file extension and make a diff

```
.bak
.bak-extract.txt
.*-extract.txt
.json
```

I tried

```
diff dir1 dir2 | sed '.txt.bak'
```

I am not able to get correct diff

Answer (score 1):

You can try to exclude those files

```
 diff -r --exclude="bak*.txt" dir1 dir2
```